# What does it mean those translations marked as #~ in the django `.po` file?

Tags: django, internationalization, po

I'm using django i18n and I've been executed `makemessages` several times to include new phrases I marked for translation while I'm developing my app.

Recently, I realised there are some translation (not many) marked as:

```
#~ msgid "Location:"
#~ msgstr "Lugar:"

#~ msgid "Sector:"
#~ msgstr "Sector:"
```

I found those entries are duplicated, since in the file the correct translations are there too:

```
#: templates/userprofile.html:63
msgid "Location"
msgstr "Lugar:"

#: tiesport/userprofile.html:69
msgid "Sector"
msgstr "Sector:"
```

What does this '#~' mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Pology manual](http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html) (section 2.5.3), those are obsolete entries:

> The last, fourth category are obsolete messages, the messages which
>   are not present in the source any more. All obsolete messages are
>   grouped at the end of the merged PO file, and fully commented out by
>   the #~ comment

I couldn't find that in the [gettext documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html), but the Pology manual also claims that "[t]here is no formal specification of the PO format; instead, the related parts of the Gettext manual serve as its working definition".

Comment: Then, I don't see why they are marked as obsolete messages and at the same time marked as for translation. It's a bit strange... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @kiril as the messages in the source code change over time, messages that are no longer used are migrated to "obsolete" -- you can remove them yourself without consequence. They are kept by `gettext` in case they can help inform translation of new messages, or if you might eventually bring those old messages back into the active source